# How do I output the campaign status from the ad account insight level (Facebook marketing api)

Tags: facebook, api, status

I am trying to output a list of all campaigns in an ad account with a few insights with it.
I was able to get all the data I wanted except the campaign effective status, for some reason its not being called out and is showing an error.

The Facebook quick start compiler shows that 'delivery' is the proper keyword to get the status.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token = 'EAAXYydBVCvUBAHBsZCegoqntZ234234ZD';
$ad_account_id = 'act_123';
$app_secret = '1123123';
$app_id = '123123123';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
  'campaign_id',
  'delivery',
  'clicks',
  'campaign_name',
);
$params = array(
  'level' => 'campaign',
  'filtering' => array(),
  'breakdowns' => array(),
  'time_range' => array('since' => '2017-08-08','until' => '2019-09-26'),
);

return (new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->getInsights(
  $fields,
  $params
)->getResponse()->getContent();
```

Comment: You should first of all go invalidate that access token you just exposed here, before someone goes and uses it to perform any actions in the name of your account, like posting on your pages.

Comment: Whoops! completely missed that. Thank you very much <3